# c# XAML unexpected vertical lines in TextBox

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox

Having next repo of textbox.  Have no idea how to get rid of vertical gray lines. I have no any Gray word or other close colors.

```
<TextBox  Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"
  Visibility="{Binding MessageLineVisible}" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
  IsReadOnly="True" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
  Height="48" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBox.Text>
      <Binding Path="MessageLine" ValidatesOnExceptions="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

[image]

Comment: and your other items in the `<Gird>` do not have those lines?

Comment: Have you inspected your app with [snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf)? Are the border lines coming from the textbox?

Comment: Row 7 does not have other controls